# Consejos para subir Proyecto ASP.Net con Rest API (MVC) y aplicación web MVC a un Hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Bien es la primara vez que subiré un proyecto a un hosting en *SMARTERASP*, ya tengo visto como suben proyectos de N-Capas a un hosting gratuito, el problema es que yo utilizo Rest API, y como consecuente utilizo varias url (localhost:xxx) en mis js.

Todo esta en la misma solución con la arquitectura de N-Capas, tanto el api como la aplicación web son están en MVC...

Mi duda esta: ¿debo cambiar las URL de mis javascript? 
¿o como le hago para adaptar mi aplicación de este tipo para un hosting?

Nota. En los ejemplos veo que solo recompilan la solución de N-Capas y sale el aplicativo y eso es lo que suben, solo cambian la cadena de conexión a la base de datos y con eso funciona a la perfección.

¿Pasaría lo mismo con mi proyecto?

Comment: no entiendo que tiene que ver el restapi con tener varias url, ya que si esto es asi es porque tienes varios proyectos en la misma solucion. Estas seguro que son varias url ? porque si el proyecto asp.net mvc es uno solo entonces la url es unica

Answer (score 1):

**>>¿debo cambiar las URL de mis javascript?**

Si usas rest entonces no veo donde aplicas javascript ya que esto son solo servicios que devuelven json, no tiene ujna interfaz visual al usuario.

Igualmente las url de los js no deberias cambiarla si es que las defines usando el ~/

**>>¿Pasaría lo mismo con mi proyecto?**

Para publicar no basta solo con compilar y subir una dll, tienes que usar las opciones de `publish` del Visual Studio proporciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con esta opcion podras seleccionar para que la publicacion sea en una carpeta local y asi luego copiarla al hosting

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que la API es un proyecto MVC aparte del sitio web y yo consumo mis APIS desde JS, en la cual pongo las "URL"
Ejemplo: http://localhost:2001/api/CatalogoEmpleados/ListaEmpleados. Esta dirección la tengo establecido en mi JS, entonces no se si funcione al subirlo al Hosting así como esta.

Answer (score -1):

A la pregunta si debes cambiar la URL de tus javascript como has comentado que tienes URL del tipo  `localhost:2001/api/CatalogoEmpleados/ListaEmpleados` directamente en el codigo.
La compilación o el proceso de deploy no la va a cambiar.

Por  lo que deberás de encargarte que este cambiada, o que se calcule de algún modo.

Yo lo que haría es añadir el dominio de la api en el config del proyecto web  para asi después poder general la URL de las llamadas REST de un modo similar a:

```
urlDomain+'/api/CatalogoEmpleados/ListaEmpleados'
```

Asi solo deberas de cambiar el config en caso de deploy.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/56583)

Comment: @IvanBotero En un comentario a otra respiuesta. el usuario indica que tiene hardcoded localhost. Ahora Edito para dejar claro este hecho